# CP2112 USB->I2C bridge not appearing in /dev

Tags: raspbian, i2c

I am trying to get a SiLabs CP2112 USB to I2C bridge working with my Pi. At some point in recent history I had it working just fine. I could plug in a CP2112 evaluation board and a new entry /dev/i2c-2 was created for a new I2C bus. For some reason this doesn't seem to work anymore. I've gone back to a stock Raspbian image and still can't get the device to appear as an I2C bus.

If I connect my CP2112 then lsusb gives me:

`Bus 001 Device 006: ID 10c4:ea90 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc.`

dmesg shows nothing bad:

`[   87.010707] usb 1-1.5: Product: CP2112 HID USB-to-SMBus Bridge
[   87.010724] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Silicon Laboratories
[   87.010740] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 0043FFF3
[  107.147142] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1438.756308] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 1438.864004] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea90
[ 1438.864030] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1438.864049] usb 1-1.3: Product: CP2112 HID USB-to-SMBus Bridge
[ 1438.864066] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Silicon Laboratories
[ 1438.864082] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 0043FFF3`

And /var/log/syslog again shows nothing that looks bad:

`Mar 11 12:40:58 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1438.756308] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Mar 11 12:40:58 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1438.864004] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea90
Mar 11 12:40:58 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1438.864030] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Mar 11 12:40:58 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1438.864049] usb 1-1.3: Product: CP2112 HID USB-to-SMBus Bridge
Mar 11 12:40:58 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1438.864066] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Silicon Laboratories
Mar 11 12:40:58 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1438.864082] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 0043FFF3
Mar 11 12:40:58 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 6: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
Mar 11 12:40:58 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 6 was not an MTP device`

The i2c-dev module is loaded. I see there has been fairly recent work on the hid-cp2112 driver in the kernel, and others appear to be able to use the device with no problems.

Can anyone offer any help or advice? Thank you.

Comment: How often do you update the kernel and firmware?

Comment: All testing of this problem has been performed with 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.

Although I am convinced I saw the bridge enumerate as i2c-2 in /dev/ I'm now checking that the Kernel was built with the driver enabled. I think I would expect to see hid-cp2112.ko in `/lib/modules/4.1.19-v7+/kernel/drivers/hid` but it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own questions to help others who may have the same problem.

The Kernel for the Pi is not compiled with the driver for the CP2112 selected as either a builtin or a loadable module. For the CP2112 to operate correctly as a USB->I2C bridge follow the guide [here](http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/Compiling-a-kernel-module-for-the-raspberry-pi-2) to rebuild the kernel, with the exception that before compiling/building you should modify the .config to allow the hid-cp2112 driver to be included as a builtin driver.

With the Kernel and modules built deploy them to your Pi/Pi2 by copying the built Kernel Image over the top of kernel.img/kernel7.img and copying the built lib folder to /lib of the Pi SD Card.

When connecting a CP2112 you should now see the I2C bus appear under /dev